# inner sql query gives alias error

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm running a query where i select the last 20 entries, unfortunately i want them in the right order.

meaning after selecting by descending, i then want to reverse it into ascending.

colums i can sort by are

'id' (unique identifier and order) and 'dtg' (unix timestamp)

My current query :

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY tablename.id DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

So i tried to fix it using an outer query..

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM (SELECT * 
               FROM tablename 
               ORDER BY tablename.id
                DESC LIMIT 20)
  ORDER BY dtg ASC;
```

But the result is 
MySQL query failed with error:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your original query, then use PHP's sort() or usort() functions to sort the results as you want them. For example, assuming your array is as set in the first part:

```
$stuff = array(
    array(
        "name"=>"alice"
        "id"=>4
        ),
    array(
        "name"=>"bob"
        "id"=>3
        ),
    array(
        "name"=>"mike"
        "id"=>2
        ),
    array(
        "name"=>"eve"
        "id"=>1
        )
    );
usort($stuff,function($a,$b){
    if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {
        return 0;
        }
    return ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

As you can see, usort() sorts the array using the named index ['id'] as the value to order.

If you're lazy, like I usually am, you can simplify the usort() to something like this:

```
usort($stuff,function($a,$b){return $a['id']<$b['id'];});
```

You can find more about usort() [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Good luck!

Comment: This worked like a charm.  

I used the short method, which reminded me of something i learned in school once,  called bubble sort, or something similar.    Just cannot remember it correctly..

Answer (score 0):

try this 
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY .id DESC LIMIT 20 and ORDER BY dtg ASC;

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
;WITH cteOrderdData
  (SELECT top 100 percent * 
               FROM tablename 
               ORDER BY tablename.id
               ASC LIMIT 20)
 select * from cteOrderdData
```